# Extending Jest's "Automatic Mock" functionality

Tags: mocking, jestjs

**Context**

Jest's "automatic mocking" functionality is very useful. I don't have to create handwritten mocks for every class, I can just do:

```
jest.mock('./src/MyObject')
```

... and I have a mock object that has all the right functions, all mocked out.

Note that I am not referred to the "automock" feature, which takes this to another level by not even requiring you to call `jest.mock()`, but rather the automatic functionality that occurs when you call `jest.mock()` without passing a mock factory (i.e. when passing only one argument).

**Goal**

I want to be able to customize this automatic mocking behavior slightly without losing all of the magic above. For context, I am trying to make Jest play nicely with third-party framework, but here are some simplified requirements:

- Drop-in replacement. You still call `jest.mock()`, you still import
  classes normally, etc. Test writers are oblivious to the
  customization.
- All of the functions of the target object still
  automatically mocked. If I add functions to that object, I don't need
  to update the mock.
- If the target object has a function named `awesomeFunction()`, I want it to be automatically mocked to return the string "awesome". (contrived example alert!)

**Where I'm stuck**

I've managed to create a function that uses `jest.genMockFromModule()` which invokes this automatic mocking behavior. I can then modify this mock as I see fit (e.g. mocking `awesomeFunction()`). Finally I can register this mock using `jest.setMock()`.

I can now use this function (let's call it `mockAwesomely()`) in my test code:

```
import MyModule from './src/MyModule'
mockAwesomely('./src/MyModule') // used to be jest.mock('./src/MyModule')
```

The problem is, with this code, the imported `MyModule` is not the mocked module. It's the real `MyModule`. After some investigation, I believe this is happening because `mockAwesomely()` is not being hoisted to the top of the file like `jest.mock()` is. Even manually putting it at the top of the file doesn't seem to work, because `import` statements are hoisted too.

I feel like I'm really close. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Sounds like you need to override `jest.mock`. The only alternative is to make jest hoist your `mockAwesomely`, but that's too complicated.

Comment: you would have to fork `babel-plugin-jest-hoist`

Comment: @HermanStarikov I did try overriding `jest.mock` from a file included via `setupFiles` configuration option. Oddly, it didn't seem to have an effect. Any thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/6d3da9be06350bfa7414b609807ebd0cbdf0c416/packages/babel-plugin-jest-hoist/src/index.js#L142 this is the function that determines whether an expression gets hoisted. It looks like having the same name should be enough. Not sure why it did not work for you.

Comment: Based on further testing, the jest object that is available to `setupFiles` appears to be a different instance than the one that is available to the test. So overriding by monkey-patching the function doesn't work. Ideas on alternative override techniques?

Comment: Fork babel-plugin-jest-hoist and all it's descendants

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @brindyblitz?